# Find permutations of a list of numbers with increasing length in C

Tags: c, permutation

Consider the following list of numbers: `0, 1, 2, 3`

I am trying to find all permutations of the list of length 2, 3 and 4.

i.e.

```
(0, 1)
(0, 2)
(0, 3)
(1, 0)
(1, 2)
(1, 3)
(2, 0)
(2, 1)
(2, 3)
(3, 0)
(3, 1)
(3, 2)
(0, 1, 2)
(0, 1, 3)
(0, 2, 1)
(0, 2, 3)
(0, 3, 1)
(0, 3, 2)
(1, 0, 2)
(1, 0, 3)
(1, 2, 0)
(1, 2, 3)
(1, 3, 0)
(1, 3, 2)
(2, 0, 1)
(2, 0, 3)
(2, 1, 0)
(2, 1, 3)
(2, 3, 0)
(2, 3, 1)
(3, 0, 1)
(3, 0, 2)
(3, 1, 0)
(3, 1, 2)
(3, 2, 0)
(3, 2, 1)
(0, 1, 2, 3)
(0, 1, 3, 2)
(0, 2, 1, 3)
(0, 2, 3, 1)
(0, 3, 1, 2)
(0, 3, 2, 1)
(1, 0, 2, 3)
(1, 0, 3, 2)
(1, 2, 0, 3)
(1, 2, 3, 0)
(1, 3, 0, 2)
(1, 3, 2, 0)
(2, 0, 1, 3)
(2, 0, 3, 1)
(2, 1, 0, 3)
(2, 1, 3, 0)
(2, 3, 0, 1)
(2, 3, 1, 0)
(3, 0, 1, 2)
(3, 0, 2, 1)
(3, 1, 0, 2)
(3, 1, 2, 0)
(3, 2, 0, 1)
(3, 2, 1, 0)
```

I need to implement this in C, but all the algorithms I have found [1,2] only give the permutations with length equal to the length of the number list, i.e. only the results from `(0, 1, 2, 3)` in the block above. Reducing the length from 4 to 3 gives only the permutations for the list `0, 1, 2`.

I can currently achieve what I want in Python using `itertools.permutation`, as shown below.

```
import itertools

MaxN = 4

for Length in range(2, MaxN + 1):
    for perm in itertools.permutations(Indices, Length):
        print perm
```

Any advice on how to implement this in C would be greatly appreciated.

[1] http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Permutations#C

[2] http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-to-print-all-permutations-of-a-given-string/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a slight modification to [2]:

```
/* Function to print permutations of string
   This function takes three parameters:
   1. String
   2. Starting index of the string
   3. Ending index of the string.
   4. Length of permutation */
void permute(char *a, int i, int n, int m) 
{
   int j; 
   if (i == m)
   {
       char temp = *(a+i);
       *(a+i) = '\0';
       printf("%s\n", a);
       *(a+i) = temp;
   }
   else
   {
       for (j = i; j <= n; j++)
       {
          swap((a+i), (a+j));
          permute(a, i+1, n, m);
          swap((a+i), (a+j)); //backtrack
       }
   }
}
```

Would be used like this:

```
char a[] = "0123";  
for (int i = 2; i <= 4; i++)
    permute(a, 0, 3, i);
```

Which gives the same result as your Python implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [combination generating algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/127704/315052) that will spit out the sequence of C(n, k) combinations for increasing k in an outer loop, and apply the P(k, k) permutation algorithm to produce the sequence of permutations for each combination.

```
c = empty_combination();
for (k = 0; k <= n; ++k) {
    do {
        c = next_combination(c, sequence, k);
        p = empty_permutation();
        do {
            p = next_permutation(p, c);
            print_permutation(p);
        } while (! is_empty_permutation(p));
    } while (! is_empty_combination(c));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple to do it in C++ . Using the (next_permutation()) method.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/next_permutation/

Answer (score 0):

Here is an iterative method for generating all the subsets!
total number of subsets is 2^n - 1
so it generates the subsets of all length.
if you want the subset of particular length just add a counter and check if you are printing of specific length.

```
main(){
int a[]={0,1,2,3};
int n=pow(2,4) - 1;
for(int i=0;i<=n;i++){
    int p = i;
    int l=0;
    while(p){
        if(p%2==1)
            printf("%d",a[l]);
        p>>=1;
        l++;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
}
```